# Copy a folder using cwd

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

```
{ 
    expand: true,
    cwd: '/static',
    src: ['**'],
    dest: '../../public/'
}
```

I'm trying to copy the static folder and all of it's content to the public folder, but the above only copies what's inside the static folder.

How can I also include the static folder in the copy?

Answer (score 0):

From [Grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically):

```
 cwd: All src matches are relative to (but don't include) this path.
```

The below from the grunt-contrib-copy [readme](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy#usage-examples):

```
  // includes files within path
  {expand: true, src: ['path/*'], dest: 'dest/', filter: 'isFile'},

  // includes files within path and its sub-directories
  {expand: true, src: ['path/**'], dest: 'dest/'},
```

Comment: Thanks - what does filter: 'isFile' do?

Comment: The filter property allows you to more accurately target what you want to copy. You can use any of the methods listed [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats). In your case you might not want to use filter, as you may want the directories as well.

Comment: @panthro, if this works for you, could you mark as correct? Thanks.